# parSapply with 2 arguments

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Is there any posibility to pass 2 arguments throught `parSapply` `parallel` function, using library `parallel` in R?

I have tried with:

```
var2 <- c(10,20,30)
myfunction<-function(var1,var2){
mean(rnorm(1000,var1,var2))
}
parSapply(cl,1:10,FUN=myfunction,var2=var2)
```

Thanks!
Jesús

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me how you want those two arguments applied. Do you want each value of var1 to be executed with each value of var2? Or do you mean first var1 with first var2, then second var1 with second var2 etc? The parallel package also offers parallel versions of other apply functions like `mcmapply`

Comment: This is only an example, but imagine that you have var1 from 1:10, and var2 is a vector, v2<-c(10,20,30)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has to work... Have you initialized cl and var2?

```
myfunction<-function(var1,var2){
mean(rnorm(1000,var1,var2))
}
n_cores <- 2 # number of cores for parallel processing
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
var2 <- 3
parSapply(cl,1:10,FUN=myfunction,var2=var2)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: It works, just one more question: It is possible to pass all the variables that I want?

Comment: I think so, if you function receives more than one arguments you have only to indicate it en parSapply function:

parSapply(cl,var1,FUN=myfunction,var2=var2,var3=var3,var4=var4)